API BingX TrailingStop
I managed to install take profit and stoploss
But I can't set the trailing stop correctly
I tried to place an order and then use its id to set trailing, but I got an error
Then I tried to set trailingstop \immediately with the order (this option is preferable)
I get the following error
{'code': 100400, 'msg': 'arguments invalid', 'timestamp': 1732693212045}
Example of the installation function trailing stop
def set_trailing_stop(order_id, symbol, trailing_callback_rate, activation_price, side, positionSide):
    try:
        if not all([order_id, symbol, trailing_callback_rate, activation_price, side, positionSide]):
            raise ValueError("Невалидные параметры для трейлинг-стопа.")

        # Преобразование и проверка параметров
        activation_price = round(float(activation_price), 2)  # Округляем до двух знаков
        trailing_callback_rate = str(round(float(trailing_callback_rate), 2))  # Преобразуем в строку

        paramsMap = {
            "symbol": symbol.replace("/", "-"),
            "orderId": str(order_id),
            "callbackRate": trailing_callback_rate,
            "activationPrice": str(activation_price),
            "side": side,
            "positionSide": positionSide,
            "type": "TRAILING_STOP_MARKET",  # Тип ордера
            "workingType": "CONTRACT_PRICE",  # Дополнительный параметр для контракта
            "reduceOnly": "false"  # Установить в false, если не нужно ограничивать ордер
        }

        logger.info(f"Setting trailing stop with: {paramsMap}")

        # Отправка запроса
        response = send_request("POST", "/openApi/swap/v2/trade/order/trailingStop", paramsMap)
        response_data = json.loads(response)

        if response_data.get('code') == 0:
            logger.info(f"Trailing stop успешно установлен для ордера {order_id} ({symbol}).")
        else:
            logger.error(f"Ошибка при установке trailing stop: {response_data}")
            send_telegram_message(f"❌ Ошибка при установке trailing stop: {response_data}")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Ошибка при установке trailing stop: {str(e)}")
        send_telegram_message(f"❌ Ошибка при установке trailing stop: {str(e)}")

